# CKEditor Padding

Tags: ckeditor, padding

Adding the following style to my page removes the rounded corners from FireFox and Chrome. (IE didn't have rounded corners to start with). In FireFox and Chrome it also removes the padding between the editor and the border but in IE it does not. I am totally stomped as to why the padding is not being removed in IE

```
span.cke_skin_kama 
{
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -o-border-radius: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solved the problem

```
span.cke_skin_kama 
{
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -o-border-radius: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```